# Updating a computed observable only sometimes

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I have a computed observable that makes AJAX calls based on other data (in a computed observable). The resulting data is used to populate part of the UI. Sometimes that part of the UI is hidden and I'd like to avoid the AJAX calls when it's hidden. Right now I have the following, but it updates whenever `isVisible` becomes `true`:

```
this.loadData = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        this.isProcessing(true);
        var self = this;
        $.when.apply($, ko.utils.arrayMap(this.parent.data.filteredSelectedDatasetLinks(), function(datasetLink) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: datasetLink.getDownloadUrl('.json'),
                success: function(data) {
                    //... do stuff with the data
                }
            });
        }))
        .done(function() {
            self.isProcessing(false);
        });
    }
}, this);
```

So obviously I need to split this up somehow, but I haven't figured out how to do it. To reiterate, when `isVisible` is false, no updates should happen. When `isVisible` is true, updates happen whenever `filteredSelectedDatasetLinks` changes. When `isVisible` becomes true, updates happen if `filteredSelectedDatasetLinks` changed while it was false.

Comment: Maybe a dirty flag on `filteredSelectedDatasetLinks` that you check before making the AJAX request and clear after a successful request?

Comment: Would the dirty flag be observable? How would you set it--another computed observable or a manual subscription?

Comment: If the only dependency is `filteredSelectedDatasetLinks` itself, then I suppose either a computed or manual subscription would be equivalent.  I would make it observable, but if you already access `filteredSelectedDatasetLinks` in the computed that you listed, then it would trigger regardless (don't need the dirty flag to trigger anything, just use to decide if more work needs to be done)

Comment: I just ran across your [post on pausing computed observables](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/pausing-notifications-in-knockoutjs.html) that's similar in concept to what I'm doing here and also suffers the side effect of re-evaluating the computed when it's resumed. This led me to try to work out a generic pauseable computed that satisfies my conditions. I'll post more in a bit.

Comment: I haven't thought much about the pauseable stuff, since throttling was added, but it is an interesting idea to try to encapsulate the logic for what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using based on RP Niemeyer's comments.

```
this.trackData = ko.computed(function() {
    this.parent.data.filteredSelectedDatasetLinks();    // for notification
    this.isDataDirty(true);
}, this);

this.loadData = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.isVisible() && this.isDataDirty()) {
        this.isDataDirty(false);
        this.isProcessing(true);
        var self = this;
        $.when.apply($, ko.utils.arrayMap(this.parent.data.filteredSelectedDatasetLinks.peek(), function(datasetLink) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: datasetLink.getDownloadUrl('.json'),
                success: function(data) {
                    //... do stuff with the data
                }
            });
        }))
        .done(function() {
            self.isProcessing(false);
        });
    }
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to call your ajax when the `filteredSelectedDatasetLinks` is changed (and only if visible?). I think the best way to do this is to make that dependency explicit using the `subscribe` function... (I have simplified slightly and fixed issue with your final 'this')

```
this.filteredSelectedDatasetLinks.subscribe(function() {
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        this.isProcessing(true);
        var self = this;
        $.when.apply($, ko.utils.arrayMap(this.filteredSelectedDatasetLinks(), function(datasetLink) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: datasetLink.getDownloadUrl('.json'),
                success: function(data) {
                    //... do stuff with the data
                }
            });
        }))
        .done(function() {
            self.isProcessing(false);
        });
    }
}, this);
```

The issue with your original attempt is that ko.computed runs the function once and automatically works out which observables it needs to subcribe to. In your case this included the `isVisible` observable (which is not what you wanted). But making it explicit with the subscribe call directly you no longer have to worry about `isVisible` firing the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't satisfy this requirement: "When isVisible becomes true, updates happen if filteredSelectedDatasetLinks changed while it was false."

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Your answer is definitely the way to go.